# Why am I getting "KeyError: 'Context'" in Python 3.8 (Anaconda/Spyder)

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I'm trying to test a function out to normalise text I believe from a tutorial I'm following on an AI chatbot (https://medium.com/swlh/a-chatbot-in-python-using-nltk-938a37a9eacc) under the section saying 'Steps involved' but I keep getting KeyError: 'Context' when I try copy this line from the tutorial into Spyder.
I've tried researching and going through the tutorial again and carefully spell checking my libraries to see if I've missed anything but I still haven't figured out why the key is missing so I was hoping someone here could please help?

**My code**

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk import pos_tag # for parts of speech
from nltk import word_tokenize # to create tokens
from nltk.stem import wordnet # to perform lemmatization
from nltk.corpus import stopwords # for stop words to end prgrm
import numpy as np
import re
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances # to perform cosine similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer # to perform tfidf
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer # to perform bow

df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\mecha\Documents\Comp Sci - Year 3\ISYS30221 - Artificial Intel\New Try - AI with revisions\dialog_talk_agent.xlsx') # excel file of predetermined questions and answers


df.ffill(axis = 0, inplace=True) # fills all null values with previous value in dataset (NaN = null values)

df1 = df.head(10)

def step1(x):
    for i in x:
        a=str(i).lower()
        p=re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9]', ' ', a)
        print(p)
```

**Code snippet I run in the console after running the earlier code**

```
step1(df1['Context'])
```

**Error feedback in the console**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Context'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-6335e79211e5>", line 1, in <module>
    step1(df1['Context'])

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Context'
```

I've researched on *KnowledgeHut* and I get that the *KeyError* is because my program can't find the 'Context' key but I've been following a somewhat recent tutorial closely so I can't tell why I'm getting the error or maybe it's because I'm missing some library?
I was hoping someone on here could help me out on this while I try and learn some basics before getting onto my AI chatbot project for school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up at the top of the page the excel file has column names 'Context' and 'Text Response' so you might be missing those in your file or spelled them wrong, that's the only way it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

`step1(df1)` should just work fine